# Sending AT Commands to (not unlocked) Baseband 3.0.04 on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone-4

I am wondering if you can send AT Commands using Minicom / sendmodem / igsm to the baseband chip which is, i believe, a Qualcomm MDM6610 / MDM6600 ?
I did not have any success trying this. There is, in addition, no /dev/*baseband*, but a /dev/tty.debug which i used. with. no. success. BUT: using minicom on the iphone (which always stated it was offline) and spamming the baseband with AT ENTER AT ENTER AT ENTER... caused the same to print two dots, a question mark and some line breaks.

Okay, here's my question: Is there a possibility for me, who did not save SHSH blobs for any old firmware, to talk to the modem? Does Signal.app actually work on a 4S?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to save old SHSH files is you want to use new iOS firmware. Also [check this link](http://dreamjb.net/2013/03/planetbeing-app-called-signal-2-download/) for updated Signal-2 app but also there is no confirmed messages about iPhone 4s support